# WPF User Control Error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I've search the forum, but I coundn't find anything that quite satisfied me.

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, when I try to add a WPF User Control I get this error:

```
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: objectType"
```

Then when I want to select the hosted content, I get this error :

```
"An error occured trying to add references for type 'PolyPuttZe.GameCanvas', or finding the type. Make sure the project references are correct."
```

I followed this tutorial : http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is the code I wrote :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;

namespace PolyPuttZe
{
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        public Game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So show some details. Is this inside an ElementHost? Did you write a method or ctor with an objectType parameter?

Comment: I followed the steps and was able to see the dropdown in winforms. Did you modified the code after you did the tutorial? Please show your code.

Comment: I didn't wrote any code ... only the one auto-generated by Visual Studio. Visual studio knows my WPF User Control in the ToolBox, but I get the mistake when I try to put it in my designer.

Comment: But what is PolyPuttZe.GameCanvas?  You've shown a bit of code for PolyPuttZe.Game.  Its PolyPuttZe.GameCanvas that has the issue.  One thing to check is naming and case-sensitivity between the controls and the event handlers - this error message has been known to occur when migrating code and only some of the code gets automatically changed.

Comment: Did you add the reference to the WPF project to the Winforms project?

Comment: I got it working!

All I did was to start all over. I deleted this project and created a new one. Then the error was gone and it was working.

Thanks to all who helped me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more useful answer for the next person that has this issue - you need to create your WPF user control and build the solution first. Then open/create the form and add an Element Host and set it to your control. This is likely what the accepted answer means as starting over would work as well if you create the WPF control first.